# Docker, mongodb don't connection nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am facing weird issue while connecting MongoDB running in a separate container from my nodejs container, it displays the following error while trying to connect to MongoDB.
My Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["npm","start"]
enter code here
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    links:
    - mongo
    - redis

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "49155:49155"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

mongo config

```
mongoose: { // MongoDB
    // uri: mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options
    uri: `mongodb://localhost:27017/${DB_NAME}`,
    options: {
    },
    seed: {
      path: '/api/models/seeds/',
      list: [
        {
          file: 'user.seed',
          schema: 'User',
          plant: 'once' //  once - always - never
        },
        {
          file: 'example.seed',
          schema: 'Example',
          plant: 'once'
        }
      ]
    },
  },
```

Issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ddao.png)

I am only studied docker pls help me

Answer (score 1):

On creating a new container, docker will attach that container to a default internal bridge. 
https://docs.docker.com/network/ check network drivers.
To make it available for the localhost 
you will have to set

`network_mode: "host"`, in docker-compose in `mongo` section

Answer (score 0):

indrajeet's answer will work, but since you are venturing into docker-compose, it is better if you treat each of your services/container as a host. In your case, the error is because your web app is trying to connect to a mongo service running on the same (web) localhost.

Instead you should connect to the mongo service/contaner, which docker-compose conveniently let your web container to access the mongo service/container/host via the hostname "mongo" ( the service name you specified in the docker-compose yaml)

My answer is to change the uri line to

> ```
> uri: `mongodb://mongo:27017/${DB_NAME}`,
> ```

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2018/10/13/437da8f228f15bc99866c9997d00ef77-full.png

That's what I get now